# Iterate through two columns and compare them

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have two columns like that:

Result-Set 1:     `select sPersonID from tPersonData where x < 50`

Result-Set 2:    `select sPersonID from tPersonData where x > 50`

I'd like to iterate through column 1 and want to check if every sPeronID is at least 1 time present in Column 2.

Sample data for Columns:

```
Result-Set 1:
00/510
00/650
00/644
00/690

Result-Set 2: 
00/510
00/640
00/644
```

And the Expected result should be like TRUE/FALSE

Comment: You don't need any loops or stored procedures for that. Add sample table data, and the expected result.

Comment: You say columns, but I'd rather say result-sets.

Comment: Better, you're almost done!

Answer (score 1):

Self join tPersonData using a left join and group by sPersonID from the left hand side and count the number of corresponding records from the right hand side:

```
select t1.sPersonID, if(count(t2.sPersonID)=0,'false','true') as result
from tPersonData t1
left join tPersonData t2 on t1.sPersonID=t2.sPersonID and t2.x>50
where t1.x<50
group by t1.sPersonID
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
select case
         when a = b then
          'TRUE'
         else
          'FALSE'
       end
  from (select (select COUNT(sPersonID)
                  from tPersonData t1
                 where t1.x < 50
                   AND t1.sPersonID IN
                       (select sPersonID from tPersonData where x > 50)) a,
               (select COUNT(sPersonID) from tPersonData t1 where t1.x < 50) b
          from dual)
```